# Cycles Rendering Speed Change

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm not sure why this is happening, but Blender has been rendering an 80 frame scene with 500 samples for around 13 hours now. It started out at a decent speed, but now it's rendering at about ONE SAMPLE PER SECOND. I'm not sure what caused it to change, but it's VERY painful, and I need to get a couple more scenes done this weekend. I don't know how I'm going to make my deadline if they all end up like this...Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Ethan

Comment: Use a render farm :-) [See this for tips on cycles speedups.](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/)

Comment: I used those tips as much as I could, but I didn't notice that I have to change the compute device under the Render tab as well as in system settings. @_@ I guess I'll let it finish rendering this one off of the CPU since it's about 70% of the way there, and hopefully it'll work after this...and I wish I had a render farm! XD

Comment: I meant PAY for a render farm. Very few people actually have the computing power of those companies.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I didn't even know that was an option. That's incredible!! Thanks so much! :)